# Strange behaviour when using Power Plans

Tags: windows-10, cpu, power-management, energy-saving, cpu-throttling

I recently wondered why my Laptop seems to be very slow (this was a verly long time). So I downloaded CPU-Z to check my CPU and saw that ist Clock is just around 998 MHZ, however it should can run at About 2.4GHZ.
I try chaning the power plan to "power mode" but Nothing changed.

Just for experimental Purpose I then go to advanced Settings -> configure TDP and switched the TDP from "17W @ 2.5 GHZ" to "13W @ 1GHZ".

For my surpise, the Clock than Change immedeatly to 2.9GHZ O.O

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

More, after every Restart the powerplan is changed to "balanced" which causes the CPU to just run at 900MHZ.

Does anyone know what can causes this behavior? Is it worse or just a minimal "error"

Comment: It almost sounds like thermal throttling. That would imply that maybe the fans have gathered dust and can't properly cool the laptop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CPU Does not run at full speed](https://superuser.com/questions/1364565/cpu-does-not-run-at-full-speed)

Comment: @LPChip however when changed the TDP to 13W it ruuns perfect over the time. Change TDP to highest never try to run the CPU above 900MHZ