# Windows 10 throttling CPU to dead slow

Tags: cpu, performance

I'm facing windows 10 slow/non-responsive behavior (perhaps after 1809 update) and after doing many fixes mentioned online (like drivers update, services on/off, windows update etc) i ended up in finding a cpu frequency change.

When i run it in safemode, it run fast as expected on correct frequency 2Ghz. (see core speed)

[image]

Where as when i run it on normal mode, starts fine but after few minutes of idle time, it changes cpu freq. way too slow 0.4Ghz. (see core speed)

[image]

Initially i thought it is due to thermal condition of cpu, so i tested it with coretemp and it seems fine.

[image]

I also tried changing power plan (default to balanced on 1809) to high performance but no result.

[image]

I also tried setting SpeedStep to 'disabled' from BIOS but no change. Also updated BIOS to latest from Dell Update App.

Can any one help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CPU Does not run at full speed](https://superuser.com/questions/1364565/cpu-does-not-run-at-full-speed)

Comment: The author confirm this question is a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1364565/cpu-does-not-run-at-full-speed/1364641#1364641) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer myself, it seems to be a close duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/a/1364641/303622).

Solution:

Another such setting is BD PROCHOT (Bi-directional Processor Hot), an emergency throttling system that is used when a CPU hits its maximum temperature. To disable it temporarily, download ThrottleStop to check on and disable BD PROCHOT. ThrottleStop when running can also correct several types of CPU throttling. Again, if this helps then something is wrong with your motherboard.

https://superuser.com/a/1364641/303622

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem but finally fixed by uninstalling PowerToys, after wasting over one week. I almost returned my laptop as a technician said it should be a hardware problem.

The culprit was the PowerToys Run utility. As soon as I disabled it, the CPU throttling was fixed instantly. I can't believe this was the culprit, but I tested multiple times by enabling and disabling and confirmed that this indeed was the culprit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).