# Why is my CPU speed so slow?

Tags: cpu

I have an Intel Core i5-6300U and it’s currently only running at 0.6GHz rather than the usual 2.50GHz its base speed is. I’ve checked the power settings and they are at 100% min and max! My CPU is not overheating…

Comment: Potential duplicate https://superuser.com/questions/1364565/cpu-does-not-run-at-full-speed it may not be throttling due to your CPU. It could be any other sensor in the system or a firmware bug. If this is a laptop then if you can pull the battery out it might reset the firmware, otherwise try the solution in the dupe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CPU Does not run at full speed](https://superuser.com/questions/1364565/cpu-does-not-run-at-full-speed)

Comment: I myself have had this problem from a failing power supply.  The power supply I had been using for years was no longer providing enough juice to allow the turbo stuff to kick in.

Comment: Can be so many reasons. Is this new, IOW it was running at higher speeds before? If so then try determining factors that are different / changes to system.